# Realm for Android: Many to Many Relationship

Tags: java, android, realm, many-to-many, object-oriented-database

I am trying to learn Realm basics by implementing a simple Android project.
The idea is that user have several items and several item lists and an item can be added to any of these lists and a list can have many items. Therefore, there is a many to many relationship between `Item` and `List` objects. Here are my objects.

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean isDone;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        isCollected = done;
    }
}

public class List extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Item> items;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RealmList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(RealmList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

My problem is, the field `isDone` might be different depending on the item's status in a given list. But when I update this field in a list, all the other items added to different lists get updated too. Since they are using the same object it makes sense but that is not to behavior I want. Is there a Realm way to create a pivot table/object with an extra column/field (in that case `isDone`) ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `But when I update this field in a list, all the other items added to different lists get updated too.` what do you mean? show code

Comment: Let say there is one Item object and I am using it in different Lists. When I change this object's isDone field, it changes in other lists too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `isDone` property of `Item` doesn't truly belong to `Item`. If you can set the same Item in multiple Lists, then the property that a given task is deemed complete within a given List is the property of the List.

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //private boolean isDone;

    @LinkingObjects("completedItems")
    private final RealmResults<List> tasksCompletedIn = null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //public boolean isDone() {
    //    return isDone;
    //}

    //public void setDone(boolean done) {
    //    isDone = done;
    //}
}

public class List extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Item> items;
    private RealmList<Item> completedItems;
```

Then you know if it's a completed item if `completedItems.contains(item)` (where `item` is a managed object, or overrides `equals` to check against only `id`)